# Get Breadcrumb Path in Custom controller Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to get breadcrumb path in my controller by using this helper

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogData, ) {
$this->catalogData = $catalogData;
}
$path = $this->catalogData->getBreadcrumbPath();
```

When I print `$path` it's giving me an empty array. But when I get this helper function in any product `phtml` file like this

```
$helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data');
$values = $helper->getBreadcrumbPath();
```

it's giving me the full path in `phtml`. How can I access this function in my controller as well?

Answer (score 0):

You will get breadcrumbpath in your custom controller by doing this:

`namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Index;`

`Class ControllerClass extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action{`

```
protected $catalogData;
protected $_pageFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogData,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
{

    $this->catalogData = $catalogData;
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}
public function execute()
{
    $path = $this->catalogData->getBreadcrumbPath();
    print_r($path);
    return $this->_pageFactory->create();
}
```

`}`

Comment: Still getting empty array

Comment: it will return breadcrumb only on catalog category and product page